# Android activity restart and Preference screen

Tags: android, android-activity, preferencescreen

I have an application with a MainActivity and few other activites. From the MainActivity I start a preference screen, where I set theme for my application.

MainActivity-> Settings->Choose Theme

`Currently how it works:`

I restart the application, start my Main activity and theme is applied to all the activites.

`How I want it to work:`

I want to restart the application and go back to the same screen where I set my Theme and not my MainActivity.

Can anyone please suggest me some ways in which I can do it?

Thank you in advance

***EDIT:***

`How I want it to work:`

Restart the application -> Go back to the "Choose Theme" Screen (Where it is set) .

Then when I press back button -> Settings screen -> and when pressed back again to my MainActivity.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best way, but you can save in `SharedPreferences` the Last screen you were on (or if it's just for this case, a boolean to know if you're coming from a restart)
and each time when the application start on `onCreate()` of `MainActivity` check the key in `SharedPreferences` and go to your `Themes` activity accordingly

Comment: Thank you for your response..But I have many options in my Settings screen ( upto 8 options) and one of them is to select the theme. So basically a two level tree.

Comment: Yes the sharedpreferences key s independant of all the options, its just one more key to tell you which activity to launch at first.Or i didn't understand you correctly ?

Comment: No..I think I will try this and will let you know if it works.

Comment: Ok I tried it.But some problems. The "choose theme" screen is not an activity but a preference provider class. So I tried to open my "Settings" screen and it worked, but when I press back button the application closes and does not go back to my MainActivity. Maybe I didnt put it properly in my question. I will edit it.

Comment: I think you need to override `onBackPressed()`. check if the settings screen is open, if yes close it, if not call `super.onBackPressed()`